# Why isn't there an article in "separated by empty space"?

Tags: articles, ambiguity

> Matter is composed of atoms separated by **empty space** through which the atoms move...

Why isn't there an article before the words "empty space"?

Comment: The apparent need for an article depends somewhat on how you parse the sentence.  "Matter is composed of atoms separated by empty space (through which the atoms move)" vs. "Matter is composed of atoms separated by [the empty space through which the atoms move].

Comment: This is a really good question. A good answer will shed a lot of light on what articles mean in English.

Comment: It is very tricky in this case, and I still don't quite get this.  Thank you and I will keep working on how to parse sentences.

Answer (score 4):

By not using an article, the author is referring to a general

> **empty** space

which is what is between all matter.

> **the** empty space

would refer to a specific empty space.

> **The** empty space between atoms...
>   The US and Europe are separated by **the** Atlantic Ocean.

where as

> **an** empty space
>   Matter is composed of atoms separated by **an** empty space

would make the empty space more specific in relation to the atoms

> The US and Europe are separated by **an** ocean.

in this case ocean is associated by its relationship to the US and Europe.

> The US is separated from Europe and Japan by ocean.

in this case it is the generic *ocean* that is being referred to.

It also helps that **empty space** is noncountable.